# How to sort results and chop off top entries in Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

We're reading in from a file that looks like this.

10036300    2

10034189    5

10035536    1

10035564    3

We need to do two things:

1 - Sort by the right column

2 - Chop off the top 3 results

So that it looks like this:

10034189    5

10035564    3

10036300    2

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For get top 3 results, better in Mapper write all values under one key:

```
context.write(NullWritable.get(),value);
```

In Reducer you can take only first three results and skip other.

2) Now all you have to do, its sort values, please search by "Hadoop secondary sort", where described SortComparator, for example http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/02/hadoop-how-to-do-secondary-sort-on_25.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Apache Pig](http://pig.apache.org/):

```
A = load '/your/file/in/hdfs' using PigStorage(' ') as (num1:long, num2:long);
B = order A by num2 desc; 
C = limit B 3;
dump C;
```